# Delphi TRegEx zero - length

Tags: regex, delphi

I want to Match the Content between '(' and ')' of

```
Path()
Path(C:\...)
```

with

```
(?<=^Path\()(.*)(?=\))
```

In Notepad++ it matches '' <-- zero length match and 'C:...'.
But using Delphi XE3:

```
if TRegEx.IsMatch(pDef, '(?<=^Path\()(.*)(?=\))') then begin
```

does only match 'C:\...' but I need the empty match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with that regex:

```
Path\((.*)\)
```

This also match the empty match, as in your example. 
[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mJ4xS7)

Comment: That's a greedy match. You want to use a lazy match surely?

Comment: The original is greedy, too, @David. And since parentheses are allowed in paths, it's plausible that a non-greedy expression would be wrong.

Comment: @David and #Rob (stupid SO one @ rule) Ok guys, I can fantasize about greedy and lazy matching, and that might actually be interesting, but seriously, can either of you point me to an article describing the difference between greedy and lazy matching and how you recognize one from the other just from the regex?

Comment: @Marjan .* greedy, .*? lazy. Greedy match is as large as possible, lazy as small as possible.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thanks. Must be the shortest article every written... :-))

Comment: But why does Notepad++ match the whole 'Path(...)' and Delphi doesn't? Isn't there a standard?

Answer (score 0):

Delphi's `TRegEx` skips all zero-length matches.  See [QC104562](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=104562) for details.

Your regex will work with Delphi's `TPerlRegEx` if you exclude `preNotEmpty` from the `State` property.

That said, using lookaround to try to isolate part of the regex match results in inefficient regexes.  Much better to use something like `Path\(([^)\r\n]*)\)` or `Path\((.*)\)` and retrieve the text matched by the first capturing group to get the actual path.  The first regex will correctly match `Path(...)` when there are additional `)` characters on the same line but will not correctly handle paths that contain `)` characters.